# Regex: I have a range of characters I'm looking for, but I want to limit possible amount of repetitions of some of them

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regex to find phone numbers in a text. Format of the phone number is unknown and it is a pretty complex topic in general, so I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible and just find POSSIBLE phone numbers (I can check them later with, for example, libphonenumber-js).

This is what I have at the moment:

```
/\+?[\d(][\d()\- ]{3,}\d/g
```

This regexp finds phone numbers which satisfy:

1. it can have "+" or not
2. then there will be a number or opening parenthesis
3. then just range of characters (numbers, parenthesis, dash or space, at least 3)
4. will end up with a number

But my regex fails at these cases:

- "+(651)-234-2345 (332)-445-12345", so here we see that the user failed to properly format phone number and forgot to add "+", and since parenthesis can repeat as many times as they want, I'm capturing it as one long number
- "+(651)-234-2345(332)-445-12345" same as before, but now the user even forgot to add space

**Is there a way to say, that parenthesis can only open and close once, or something like that?**
I mean they can appear anywhere in the number, not only in the beginning, but just once.

I have a playground here: https://regexr.com/7lgni
As you can see, most of the phone numbers are highlighted as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Don't mix `()` in with the digits. Just match one optional sequence beginning with `(`, ending with `)`, with digits in between. Then match combinations of digits, dashes, and spaces after that.

```
\+?(?:\(\d+\))?[\d\-\s]{3,}\d
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uWWFty/1)

Comment: This was also very useful, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Given the relaxed requirements of a single, optional parenthesis  pair and no
following dash without accompanying digit.

```
\+?(?:(?:(?:\(\d+\))[\d -]*|\d[\d -]*(?:\(\d+\))?[\d -]*)\d)(?![\d-])
```

https://regex101.com/r/t4h94x/1

```
\+? 
(?:
   (?:
      (?: \( \d+ \) )               # Parenth at beginning
      [\d -]*  
    | 
      \d 
      [\d -]* 
      (?: \( \d+ \) )?              # Optional parenth in the middle
      [\d -]* 
   )
   \d 
)
(?! [\d-] )
```

Comment: Can you please explain me the last part about negative lookahead? Is it just to ignore the phone number with letters? Well, I mean I see that it's the only thing it affects. Just don't quite understand how it works.

Comment: Actually I forgot about one more possibility. For example number can be of that format: "+44 (20) 1234 5678" or even "+33 1 23 (45) 67 89" (but the last one can be ignored, probably, since it's probably invalid)

Comment: @thegr0m - Ok. Posted a revision allowing optional Parenth pair in the middle. Still only a single pair allowed per ph-numb. It could also control the maximum / minimum amount of digits if the engine were pcre. This would be done in post processing in the case of JS engine. So, you can get 95% viable samples using this,imo. And in the case of the assertion `(?! [\d-] )`, it's a boundary guardian to both keep the match until the last digit allowed and prevent ph-number co-mingling.